# Why is the running time of radix-sort minimized when the base of the digits is equal to the number of numbers to be sorted?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In CSLR page 199 they state:

> Lemma 8.4: Given n b-bit numbers and any positive integer r <= b, RADIX-SORT correctly sorts these numbers in O((b/r)(n + 2^r)) time if the stable sort it uses takes O(n + k) time for inputs in the range 0 to k.

As an example to understand this there is the following, where I follow along with what I think is the CSLR reasoning (and ask questions):

We start with n 32-bit numbers (b = 32). We have n numbers that can take values from 0 to 2^32 - 1. If we run radix-sort it would involve one pass through the numbers, in which counting-sort is used with variable k (which represents the range 0 to k in which the n numbers fall) equal to 2^32 - 1. Counting sort is O(n + k), so if k >> n, we get a very bad running time for variable sizes of n.

What we do now is split each of the 32-bit numbers into, say four 8-bit numbers. This means r = 8, and so each of these four numbers now has range 0 to 2^8 - 1 = 255. d = b / r = 32 / 8 = 4 is the number of digits in each of the n numbers.

**My first question is: can we view the number 256 as the new base for each of the four 8-bit numbers? Do we now have four base-256 digits?**

Now when we use radix-sort, we have to do four passes instead of one (counting-sort is used four times). Each pass is O(n + k) but now k is 2^8 - 1 = 255 not 2^32 - 1. So the total running time is O(4*(n + 255).

So when we split the initial number into smaller r-bit numbers, we increase the number of radix-sort passes, but decrease the range of values in counting-sort. There seems to be an optimal r that minimizes the running time.

**Second question: There is a paragraph on p.199 that seems to argue that there is such a value of r that minimizes the expression O((b/r)(n+2^r)). Can someone provide a better explanation? I cannot get my head around it. **

> For given values of n and b, we wish to choose the value of r, with r
>   <=  b, that minimizes the expression (b/r)(n + 2^r). If b < lg(n),
>   then for any value of r <= b, we have that (n + 2^r) = O(n). Thus,
>   choosing r = b yields a running time of (b/b)(n + 2^b), which is
>   asymptotically optimal. If b  >= lg(n), then choosing r = lg(n)
>   gives the best time to within a constant factor, which we can see as
>   follows. Choosing r = lg(n) yields a running time of O(bn/lg(n)). As
>   we increase r above lg(n), the 2^r term in the numerator increases
>   faster than the r term in the denominator, and so increasing r above
>   lg(n) yields a running time of Omega(bn/lg(n)). If instead we were to
>   decrease r below lg(n), then the b/r term increases and the n + 2^r
>   term remains at O(n).

On MIT opencourseware (Lecture 7 Course Notes), in one of their algorithms courses they show the minimization slightly differently:
counting-sort runs in O(n + b), where b is the base in which the numbers are expressed. So if the n numbers are in range 0 to k, each has d = log base b of k digits, where each digit is a number between 0 and b - 1. So b is now what k was in the previous example from CSLR. Radix-sort does d passes of counting-sort, so the total running time is O(d(n + b)) = O((n + b)*(log base b of k)). This is minimized when b is chosen to be n. **How is this related to the CSLR discussion above on the same topic.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer here. First question - 256 would be the base number, and there would be four 8 bit digits in a 32 bit integer. Missing from the article is that it takes one read pass of the data to create a matrix of counts which is then converted into a matrix of indices (or pointers). In this case the matrix is [4][256]. After creating the matrix, then it takes 4 read / write radix sort passes to sort the dataset.

Second question - For a math based explanation, the derivative of (b/r)(n+2^r) = (b (2^r (r log(2) - 1) - n))/r^2. A minimum (or maximum) occurs when the derivative == 0, which occurs when 2^r (r log(2) - 1) - n = 0. For n == 2^20 (about 1 million), r ~= 16.606232 results in O() ~= 2212837. Some example values and O():

```
 r   O
18   2330169
17   2220514
16   2228224
15   2306867
12   2807125
 8   4195328
```

However, due to cache issues, the optimal value for r versus n becomes smaller. On my system (Intel 2600K, 3.4ghz), for n = 2^20, r = 8 is fastest. At around n = 2^24, r = 10.67, using 3 fields 10, 11, 11 is fastest. At around n = 2^26, r = 16 is fastest. Again, due to cache issues, there's not a lot of difference in performance, less than 10% for r = 8 versus r = 16.