# When does grouping in radix-sort give an advantage?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, sorting

I have been testing [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Radix_sort) implementation of radix-Sort:

```
public void RadixSort(int[] a)
{  
// our helper array 
int[] t=new int[a.Length]; 

// number of bits our group will be long 
int r=4; // try to set this also to 2, 8 or 16 to see if it is quicker or not 

// number of bits of a C# int 
int b=32; 

// counting and prefix arrays
// (note dimensions 2^r which is the number of all possible values of a r-bit number) 
int[] count=new int[1<<r]; 
int[] pref=new int[1<<r]; 

// number of groups 
int groups=(int)Math.Ceiling((double)b/(double)r); 

// the mask to identify groups 
int mask = (1<<r)-1; 

// the algorithm: 
for (int c=0, shift=0; c<groups; c++, shift+=r)
{ 
    // reset count array 
    for (int j=0; j<count.Length; j++)
        count[j]=0;

    // counting elements of the c-th group 
    for (int i=0; i<a.Length; i++)
        count[(a[i]>>shift)&mask]++; 

    // calculating prefixes 
    pref[0]=0; 
    for (int i=1; i<count.Length; i++)
        pref[i]=pref[i-1]+count[i-1]; 

    // from a[] to t[] elements ordered by c-th group 
    for (int i=0; i<a.Length; i++)
        t[pref[(a[i]>>shift)&mask]++]=a[i]; 

    // a[]=t[] and start again until the last group 
    t.CopyTo(a,0); 
} 
// a is sorted 
}
```

And I don't quite understand why you would set r to a different value than b.
I got the best results by always setting it to the b value. What would be an example where I get an advantage from using a smaller value than b?

Edit: This only works if you don't use the full range of the input type:
Example: using an int[] as input will only sort with r = b if you use r = b < 32. So in the case b = 32 you need to set r to 16

Comment: There's the ideal case (no cache considerations) from a text book and actual numbers in this old thread: [radix sort optimal base](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190999/why-is-the-running-time-of-radix-sort-minimized-when-the-base-of-the-digits-is-e/36191869)

Comment: @rcgldr thanks! just what I was looking for. So I actually have the optimal O(2n + 2^r) runtime when b=r. So If I don't need exact precision, I can create 'buckets' of values with a cutoff by adjusting r and normalizing the input? (setting r=b=2 will yield 3 buckets, r=b=3 will yield 7 etc and I can just grab the subset I am interested in by catching the prefix and count? Now I just need a valid reason to use this, as I am only slightly beating a simple if/else inside a loop with fetching the case I am interested in with radix :P

Comment: Even if you had the memory, r == b == 32 would not be ideal unless the array to be sorted is is > 91 billion elements (an estimate, I don't have an easy way to verify this) in an idealized case and much larger when considering cache issues. Also r == b for integers could be implemented as a counting sort. Side note - the code you have for radix sort doesn't deal with negative integers.

Comment: You can improve the performance of the radix sort by using a single pass to create the counts and prefixes. I used a matrix in this [C++ example radix sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271367/radix-sort-implemented-in-c/40457313#40457313) .

Comment: @rcgldr the example I posted only performs a single pass for r==b,.. It performs 10 times faster than quicksort. My input isn't bigger than  4000 so I set r and b to 12.  However, I actually don't need a perfect sorting. I can go up to 40 times faster than q sort by only using 2 bits for r and b.. then I don't have perfect sorting, but the input is seperated into 3 groups,.. for inputmax = 4000 group 1 would be [0,1333[ group 2 ]1333,2666[.. etc.. Usecase is avoid doing if/else and just getting the if group by returning group1 with radix

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand using 2 bits to separate 4000 elements into groups of 3, since 4000 / 3 is not a power of 2.

If the range of values is 0 to 4000, and the size of the array is >= 4000, counting sort would be faster:

```
#define SORTMAX 4000
void CountSort(int a[], size_t n)
{
    size_t cnt[SORTMAX + 1];
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= SORTMAX; i++)
        cnt[i] = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cnt[a[i]]++;    // no out of range check
    for (size_t j = 0, i = 0; i <= SORTMAX; i++)
        while (cnt[i]--)
            a[j++] = (int)i;
}
```

Comment: 4000/3 = 1333,3. => every value below 1333,3 is set to 0; every value aboveOrequal to 1333,3 and below 2666,6 is set to 1 ... etc, then do the radix on that.  I didn't know about countsort,.. looks like it just saves me the prefixarray by replacing it with the while(cnt[i]--)?