# Creating Customized List for Radix Sort

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, linked-list, radix-sort

Given below is the code for integer Radix Sort that uses a modified Bucket Sort to sort an array. The bucket Sort uses an array of lists, where the number of lists is same as the base(8-octal, 10-decimal, 16-hex).

The digit 'i' that is obtained by the radix operation is pushed in List 'i' of the list array. Actually its not the digit but the index in input array which is pushed to the list. This requires a scan of the input array, hence time taken is O(n). After that, the indices are retrieved list by list, i.e. all the indices in the previous list are first dealt with before moving to the next list is the list array, and then the temporary result is put into temp_array.

Finally a swapping of array pointers avoids the need to copy the temp_array to input_array. When the radix decrements, then the list array is reinitialized to new memory locations. This way avoids the need of list.remove(index) method whose time complexity is O(n), because of the shifting of elements. **Will the old memory locations be cleared by JVM during execution or will they finally lead to memory overflow?**

Deletion from list at index 0 and last index(=N), ( list.remove(0), list.remove(N) ) **Which among these approach is faster?**

Is it a good idea ( will it run faster ) to create a customized List ( for holding buckets ) with 2 remove methods ( remove1() , remove2() ) where one of them removes an item from the beginning ( required for ascending order ) of the list in O(1) time, and other at the end ( required for descending order ) in same O(1) time ( without the need for shifting the elements and also supporting random access of arrayList )? (I think it may not be possible to have both.)

If yes, then what would be the necessary code lines and imported classes ?

In case of no, any other method to improve upon the speed of the algorithm ?

Does changing the base, change the performance i.e. is performance dependent on base? In case of yes, what is the an optimal base?

Any ideas on how to convert it to a multithreaded version? I think its not possible.

```
import java.util.List ;
import java.util.ArrayList ;

public class Radix_Sort
{
    // input_array[] -> the array to be sorted
    // temp_array[] -> the array to hold the temporary result, must be equal to or larger than input_array in size
    // radix -> is the number of digits in maxiumum value in array : floor of log(MaxValue)
    // length -> length of input_array[]
    // base -> Base of the number system used

    public static int[] ASC(int input_array[], int temp_array[], int radix, int length, int base)
    {
        int div = 1 ;
        int swap[] ;
        int i, s_indx, Y, j ;
        while(radix > 0)
        {
            List<List<Integer>> buckets = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(base) ;
            i = 0 ;
            while(i < base)
            {
                buckets.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()) ;
                i++ ;
            }
            i = 0 ;
            while(i < length)
            {
                buckets.get(( input_array[i] / div ) % base ).add(i) ;
                i++ ;
            }
            s_indx = 0 ;
            i = 0 ;
            while(i < base)
            {
                Y = buckets.get(i).size() ;
                j = 0 ;
                while(j < Y)
                {
                    temp_array[s_indx++] = input_array[buckets.get(i).get(j)] ;
                    j++ ;
                }
                i++ ;
            }
            swap = input_array ;
            input_array = temp_array ;
            temp_array = swap ;
            div = div * base ;
            radix--;
        }
        return input_array ;
    }

    public static int[] DSC(int input_array[], int temp_array[], int radix, int length, int base)
    {
        int div = 1 ;
        int swap[] ;
        int i, s_indx, Y ;
        while(radix > 0)
        {
            List<List<Integer>> buckets = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(base) ;
            i = 0 ;
            while(i < base)
            {
                buckets.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()) ;
                i++ ;
            }
            i = 0 ;
            while(i < length)
            {
                buckets.get(( input_array[i] / div ) % base ).add(i) ;
                i++ ;
            }
            s_indx = length - 1 ;
            i = 0 ;
            while(i < base)
            {
                Y = buckets.get(i).size() ;
                while(Y > 0)
                {
                    Y-- ;
                    temp_array[s_indx--] = input_array[buckets.get(i).get(Y)] ;
                }
                i++ ;
            }
            swap = input_array ;
            input_array = temp_array ;
            temp_array = swap ;
            div = div * base ;
            radix--;
        }
        return input_array ;
    }
}// end of class
```

Comment: Add the **'java'** tag to maximize the number of viewers !!!

Comment: @J.Piquard, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> any other method to improve upon the speed of the algorithm ?

Instead of using lists of lists, the code could allocate a matrix and fill it with counts of occurrences of each "digit" for each element of the original array in a single pass of the original array. The counts could then be converted into starting (or ending) indices for bucket boundaries for each "digit". This allows a single temp array of the same size as the original array to be used to contain the "buckets" on each radix sort pass. The method you use of swapping references (in C or C++ this would be swapping pointers) between temp and original during the radix sort is optimal.

Example C++ code for base 256 radix sort:

[Radix Sort Base 16 (Hexadecimals)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350577/radix-sort-base-16-hexadecimals/40353123#40353123)

> is performance dependent on base? In case of yes, what is the an optimal base?

The optimal base depends on the size of each element and the number of elements to be sorted. The answer in this thread explains the ideal case, and the realistic case due to cache issues:

[Why is the running time of radix-sort minimized when the base of the digits is equal to the number of numbers to be sorted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190999/why-is-the-running-time-of-radix-sort-minimized-when-the-base-of-the-digits-is-e/36191869#36191869)

> Any ideas on how to convert it to a multithreaded version

The simplest way is to split up the array into k sub-arrays (assuming k effective cores), sort the k sub-arrays in parallel (using any sort method, including radix sort), then merge the k sorted sub-arrays.